# Symfony - Sonata-Admin menu group translation

Tags: symfony, translation, sonata-admin

i have a problem with translation of group in admin menu. Its translates labels but not groups:

services:
    sonata.admin.language:
        class: App\Bundle\LanguageBundle\Admin\LanguageAdmin
        tags:
            - name: sonata.admin
              manager_type: orm
              group: "admin.menu.group.language"
              label: "admin.menu.group.item.languages"
        arguments:
            - ~
            - App\Bundle\LanguageBundle\Entity\Language
            - ~

```
sonata.admin.language_pair:
    class: App\Bundle\LanguageBundle\Admin\LanguagePairAdmin
    tags:
        - name: sonata.admin
          manager_type: orm
          group: "admin.menu.group.language"
          label: "admin.menu.group.item.language_pairs"
    arguments:
        - ~
        - App\Bundle\LanguageBundle\Entity\LanguagePair
        - ~
```

anyone can help???

Answer (score 2):

When I added

```
label_catalogue: "YourBundleName"
```

into 'tags' section, it helps me to translate label of group.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the suggested answers didn't work for me: it still was not translated.
Here's what I had to do:

1. For some reason, label_catalogue: "messages" and even a call to [setTranslationDomain, [messages]] didn't change anything: Symfony would still look for the string to translate inside of SonataAdminBundle.en.yml (I use yml files).
2. Therefore, create a file SonataAdminBundle.en.yml (or xml, whichever you use) inside app/Resources/translations/, and add your group string in there:

   ```
   admin:
       menu:
           group:
               language: Language
   ```
3. In your config.yml, add these lines under sonata_admin:

   ```
   sonata_admin:
       [...]
       dashboard:
           groups:
               admin.menu.group.language: ~
   ```
4. Clear cache. Important! It somehow was not translating it until I did this.

Also use Symfony translation debugger to learn where it's looking for some strings.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The menu groups labels are translated using 'SonataAdminBundle' domain, but items labels - using 'messages' domain or domain defined in $translationDomain variable in your Admin class.

Answer (score 1):

For me a combination of @Andrey and @Catalins answer did the trick:

`config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml`

```
sonata_admin:
    ...

    dashboard:
        blocks:
        -
            position: left
            type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list

        groups:
            app.admin.group.cms:
                label: 'app.admin.group.cms'
                label_catalogue: 'messages' # <--- this is not the bundle name, but the "translation domain" / filename of the translation file
                items:
                    - app.admin.page
                roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN']

    ...
```

and in `translations/messages.en.yml`:

```
app:
  admin:
    group:
      cms: CMS
    pages:
      label: Pages
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add a "translation" node:

`translation: YourBundle`